# Laravel WHERE ALL IN or Nothing

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I'm making a system to filter demands of the user and for one part I must filter by all attributes selected, here is my query builder :

```php
    return EncyclopedieModel::with('stats')
        ->join('equipement_stats', 'equipement_stats.id_equipement', '=', 'equipement.id_equipement')
        ->join('stats', 'stats.id_stats','=','equipement_stats.id_stats')
        ->whereIn('stats.id_stats', $filterStats)
        ->whereIn('id_typeequipement', $filterEquipement)
        ->whereIn('id_rarete', $filterRarity)
        ->skip(0 + $toskip)
        ->take(10)
        ->get()
        ->toJson();
```

I must filter on multiple demands for stats.

I firstly take all equipements that fit the demand of the user then I get the statistics of the item with eager loading.

My problem is that I must get item that has both stats at the same time. For example if my item has the statistic "3" and "7" I must get all items that have both these statistics.

Now, I'm getting all equipements with the statistic "3" and all equipements with the statistic "7"...

I don't know how I should implement it

***EDIT : I tried so simplifize with a car and caracteristics***

```php
    [
  {
    "id_car":1,
    "nom_car":"Car A",
    "rarity": 1,
    "caracteristic":[
      {
        "id_caracterstic":3,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic A"
      },
      {
        "id_caracterstic":8,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic W"
      },
      {
        "id_caracterstic":4,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_car":2,
    "nom_car":"Car B",
    "rarity": 2,
    "caracteristic":[
      {
        "id_caracterstic":5,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic P"
      },
      {
        "id_caracterstic":8,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic W"
      },
      {
        "id_caracterstic":12,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic ZA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_car":1,
    "nom_car":"Car C",
    "rarity": 2,
    "caracteristic":[
      {
        "id_caracterstic":12,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic P"
      },
      {
        "id_caracterstic":8,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic W"
      },
      {
        "id_caracterstic":14,
        "nom_stats":"Caracteristic ZDD"
      }
    ]
  },
    ]
```

It's like I must find cars in my database which rarity is "2" and caracteristics are 8 and 12.

The way I'm doing now, I'm getting Car A, Car B and Car C because my query looks through all cars with caracteristic 8 and all cars with caracteristic 12

What I want is to only get Car B and Car C when I'm looking for a car with caracteristic "8" and "12"

Comment: This is more of an SQL problem, than a Laravel problem. Can you provide some sample data, and the expected output based on that data?

Comment: I edited my original post to be more clear and to bring a less complex situation

Comment: It sounds like you just need to add a `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clause to your query. E.g. `->havingRaw('count(stats.id_stats) = ?', count($filterStats))->groupBy('encylopedie.id_car')`. I haven't tested this, so won't post it as an actual answer yet.

Comment: Thanks for helping! It seems to work but not perfectly... When I try with a WHERE IN (3, 1, 32) I got equipements that have these three characteristics but there is one with only 2 of them for no reason. Also the count does not work havingRaw expects an array

Comment: Nevermind it works, can you explain me please? I didn't really understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, my understanding is that you want to filter your models to include only those that have all of the requisite equipment types.

With that in mind, you simply need to modify your existing query to use `HAVING` and `GROUP BY`.

```
return EncyclopedieModel::with('stats')
    ->join('equipement_stats', 'equipement_stats.id_equipement', '=', 'equipement.id_equipement')
    ->join('stats', 'stats.id_stats','=','equipement_stats.id_stats')
    ->whereIn('stats.id_stats', $filterStats)
    ->whereIn('id_typeequipement', $filterEquipement)
    ->whereIn('id_rarete', $filterRarity)
    ->groupBy('enclopedie.id_car')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(id_typeequipement) = ?', [count($filterEquipement)])
    ->skip(0 + $toskip)
    ->take(10)
    ->get()
    ->toJson();
```

The `GROUP BY` is required to group the equipment types per distinct model for comparision later. The `HAVING` is essentially a `WHERE` clause applied to an aggregate function. In this case, `COUNT`.

So we want to find all models that exactly match the number of specified equipment types.

**Edit - HAVING definition**

> A HAVING clause in SQL specifies that an SQL SELECT statement should only return rows where aggregate values meet the specified conditions. It was added to the SQL language because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: I made it work but I wasn't really understanding how the "HAVING" was working here so I asked you. Thanks you again!

Comment: This is the Wikipedia definition - `A HAVING clause in SQL specifies that an SQL SELECT statement should only return rows where aggregate values meet the specified conditions. It was added to the SQL language because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.`

Comment: One last question : can I ignore the having count? If no tags are used it will still use the having count with a demand of 38 in my case. If there are no tags I don't want the having count to be performed because it will lead to no results.

Comment: Yep, you only need to use it when you want to enforce the chosen filters.

Comment: And how does it look like in an Eloquent query? I had this problem previously but I managed to take an other way because I wasn't able to solve it!

Comment: Just omit the call to the `havingRaw` function when building your query.